# No notifications when screen protection is active

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, notifications, 4.4-kitkat, custom-roms

Running Galaxy S3 and Kitkat I don't have any notifications (eg. reminders) when the device is locked with any method (pattern, pin etc.).

When the screen is off and the protection not active yet, the notifications work ok.

How do I debug and resolve this problem?

Comment: Is this on a custom ROM? According to Sammobile, there's no official 4.4 update for the Galaxy S3 yet.

Comment: @DanHulme Yes, It's AOKP based Omega rom.

Comment: @DanHulme: Android 4.4 (KitKat) is only available to the S3 LTE/4G edition. All other S3 can only get Android 4.3 and no more.

Comment: @Sfisioza Since nobody has any better suggestions, I'd suggest you simply change to a ROM that doesn't have this problem.